# Jquery select 3rd element previous in the sibling

Tags: jquery

Given a list of DIV

```
<div>1</div>
<div>2</div>
<div>3</div>
<div>4</div>
<div id="thisIsTheStart">5</div>
<div>6</div>
```

How can I select the 3rd last sibling (answer is 2) from the thisIsTheStart selector?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could combine the methods [`.eq()`](https://api.jquery.com/eq/) and [`.prevAll()`](https://api.jquery.com/prevAll/).

```
$('#thisIsTheStart').prevAll().eq(2)
```

Since the `.eq()` method's index is zero-based, you would use `.eq(2)`, which is 3.

```js
$('#thisIsTheStart').prevAll().eq(2).css('color', '#f00');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>1</div>
<div>2</div>
<div>3</div>
<div>4</div>
<div id="thisIsTheStart">5</div>
<div>6</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use prevAll() and eq().

```
$('div[id="thisIsTheStart"]').prevAll().eq(2).html();
```

**Demo:**

http://jsfiddle.net/e93ak8xo/1/